# Custom ransacker returns error - undefined method `gsub' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel, ransack

I am using Ransack in my Rails 3.2.11 app and love it. I'm currently searching Profiles that match a given high school like so:

```
<%= f.check_box :profile_high_school_cont, {}, "#{current_user.profile.high_school}", '' %>
```

However I'd like to add some additional logic to this and further refine the search to Profiles that allow other users to find them by their high school.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to add a check for whether a Profile's :show_high_school is true in addition to whether a Profile's :high_school contains certain text.

After poking around (specifically [here](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/36) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969678/howto-set-a-default-condition-with-fieldname-on-ransack)), I tried the following custom ransacker:

```
ransacker :by_high_school,
  :formatter => proc {
    |high_school| Profile.where(:high_school => high_school, :show_high_school => true)
  } do |parent|
    parent.table[:user]
  end
```

I added that both to the User model, which has_one profile, and the Profile model, which belongs_to User. In each case I get an error:

```
undefined method `gsub' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

When defined in Profile.rb I get the error with the following:

```
User.search(:profile_by_high_school_cont => "Cent").result
```

My DB is PostgreSQL